# Python partitioning function needs optimization

Tags: python, optimization, data-partitioning

While researching for a  [project euler exercise (#78)](http://projecteuler.net/problem=78), I've learned that in order to partition a number you can create a power series.  From that series you can expand and use the terms coefficient to get the number of ways to partition a particular number.

From there, I've created this small function:

```
## I've included two arguments, 'lim' for the number you wish to partition and 'ways' a list of numbers you can use to partition that number 'lim'. ##

def stack(lim,ways):

    ## create a list of length of 'lim' filled with 0's. ##
    posi = [0] * (lim + 1)

    ## allow the posi[0] to be 1 ##
    posi[0] = 1

    ## double loop -- with the amount of 'ways'. ##
    for i in ways:
        for k in range(i, lim + 1):
            posi[k] += posi[k - i]

    ## return the 'lim' numbered from the list which will be the 'lim' coefficient. ##
    return posi[lim] 

>>> stack(100,[1,5,10,25,50,100])
>>> 293
>>> stack(100,range(1,100))
>>> 190569291
>>> stack(10000,range(1,10000))
>>> 36167251325636293988820471890953695495016030339315650422081868605887952568754066420592310556052906916435143L
```

This worked fine on relatively small partitions but, with not with this exercise. Are there ways to speed this up possibly with recursion or a faster algorithm?  I've read some places that using pentagonal numbers is a way to help with partitions too.

Now I don't need to return the actually number on this problem but, check if it is evenly divisible by 1000000.

Update:  I ended up using the [pentagonal number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem#Example_program).  I am going to be attempting to use the Hardy-Ramanujan asymptotic formula that Craig Citro had posted.

Comment: Is it possible that you can supply an example of input to that function, and it's output? Both a quick case, and a 'too long' case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally checked this fact recently, but the title of "fastest partition algorithm" is likely still held by the implementation in Sage.  You can see it mentioned in [the docs](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/combinat/partition.html?highlight=number_of_partitions#sage.combinat.partition.number_of_partitions), or better yet simply skip to [the source code](http://hg.sagemath.org/sage-main/file/45c4da67d234/sage/combinat/partitions.pyx#l23). If you're looking for a discussion of ways to compute this number, the [original thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sage-devel/qV1kMXvtKNQ/discussion) leading to this implementation is definitely interesting. The [source file for the implementation itself](http://hg.sagemath.org/sage-main/file/45c4da67d234/sage/combinat/partitions_c.cc#l1) starts with some useful comments about the code.

Comment: Those are some awesome links, they will be a very helpful resource thanks.  I must have misunderstood, I didn't think the Hardy-Ramanujan Asymptotic formula was exact or even accurate enough for this purpose.  I was thinking it could only give an approximation.  I am going to see if I can use[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function_formulas) to write my own function.